# Delete related models with Django Rest Framework API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I use the Django Rest Framework to delete a User, the associated UserProfile object also gets deleted. I would like for the reverse relationship to also be true. How can I do this?

I have a Django model that represents a User's profile.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    preferred_name = models.CharField(max_lengths=100)
    #other fields here
```

Here are my Views:

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """ 
    API endpoint that represents a single user.
    """
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserProfileDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """ 
    API endpoint that represents a single UserProfile
    """
    model = UserProfile
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

And the serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name = 'userprofile-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'profile')

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('url', 'preferred_name', 'user')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could overwrite the delete method at your UserProfile class, like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    preferred_name = models.CharField(max_lengths=100)
    #other fields here
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user.delete()
        super(UserProfile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```